# as I can cover, not hide, the status bar with a view?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried the following but it has not worked for me

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self.info.view];
```

I found everything about it is to hide the status bar, but not to cover it with a view.

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cover the status bar, because it is a window belonging to the system and is in front of your app. Nor is there any reason why you should *want* to do so, since you can always hide it if you don't it to appear.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there any way to hide the status bar from the view, with the action of a button, for example? I tried this but it did not work:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
The most common way to do it I do not care for hiding the status bar when loading the view:

Answer (score 1):

In addition to matt's answer:

If you want to hide it, you have to override the following method in each viewcontroller:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Or you can just set **View controller-based status bar appearance** in Info.plist. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Many thanks. The way you say I use it too, the problem is that, in this case, I would be interested to hide the status bar to a method of a button, once loaded the view.